# Does Angular accept properties with a hyphen in them?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, templates

I'm building my first full-fledged angular app, and ran into an interesting quirk. I have a model whose data structure is something like this:

```
{
    id: "12345",
    host: {
        name: "someHostServer",
        ip-addresses: [
           "1.2.3.4",
           "10.11.12.13"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am rendering a page where this structure is assigned to 'data' in the context, like approximately so:

ID: `{{data.id}}`

Host: `{{data.host.name}}`
  IP Addresses:

```
<span ng-repeat="address in data.host.ip-addresses">
     {{address}}<br />
</span>
```

ID will show up, host name will show up, but addresses? Nothin'. Is this because of the hyphen in ip-addresses? If so, is there a simple way to do a data transform? I'm getting this data from a simple `$resource` factory.

Comment: There is no "address" property, especially without `data.host.` in front of it. If you have an invalid identifier as a key, use bracket notation: `IP Addresses: {{data.host['ip-addresses']}}`

Comment: Yes, thank you, I apologize, initially I did a quick condense of the code that I have, and obviously (shamefully) did not test it before posting it - it was the bracket notation I did not realize I could use in a template. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `.` (dot) to get object property, it can't have `-`(hyphen) in property name.

So you must use `['property-name']` to access it.

```
<span ng-repeat="address in data.host['ip-addresses']">
     {{address}}<br />
</span>
```

Comment: PErfect! Thank you, I didn't know I could reference with brackets, I feel silly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it doesn't accept properties with hyphens, it's that it is not valid json which will error out in javascript regardless of angular.

If your data was instead this:

```
{ id: "12345", host: { name: "someHostServer, "ip-addresses": [ "1.2.3.4", "10.11.12.13" ] } }
```

It would be ok, and you can try that out in chrome dev by doing this:

```
console.log({ "name": "someHostServer", "ip-addresses": [ "1.2.3.4", "10.11.12.13" ] });
```

Doing this:

```
console.log({ id: "12345", host: { name: "someHostServer, ip-addresses: [ "1.2.3.4", "10.11.12.13" ] } });
```

Results in an error.

Once you've made that change it looks like your markup should be

```
IP Addresses: {{data.host['ip-address']}}
```